# Memory error when calling gl.GenVertexArrays

Tags: opengl, go, vertex-array-object, go-gl

I've been using Go's go-gl package for quite a while now. Everything was working 100% until I did some refactoring and now I'm getting the stranges error:

```
fatal error: unexpected signal during runtime execution
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x0]

runtime stack:
runtime.throw(0x65d0fe, 0x2a)
    /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/panic.go:596 +0x95
runtime.sigpanic()
    /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/signal_unix.go:274 +0x2db
runtime.asmcgocall(0x8, 0x97ed40)
    /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:633 +0x70

goroutine 1 [syscall, locked to thread]:
runtime.cgocall(0x5b8ad0, 0xc420049c00, 0xc4200001a0)
    /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/cgocall.go:131 +0xe2 fp=0xc420049bc0 sp=0xc420049b80
github.com/go-gl/gl/v4.5-core/gl._Cfunc_glowGenVertexArrays(0x0, 0xc400000001, 0xc42006c7d8)
    github.com/go-gl/gl/v4.5-core/gl/_obj/_cgo_gotypes.go:4805 +0x45 fp=0xc420049c00 sp=0xc420049bc0
github.com/go-gl/gl/v4.5-core/gl.GenVertexArrays(0x1, 0xc42006c7d8)

...

runtime.main()
    /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/proc.go:185 +0x20a fp=0xc420049fe0 sp=0xc420049f88
runtime.goexit()
    /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2197 +0x1 fp=0xc420049fe8 sp=0xc420049fe0

goroutine 17 [syscall, locked to thread]:
runtime.goexit()
    /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2197 +0x1
exit status 2

shell returned 1
```

I was wondering if anyone has a solution. I've updated my drivers and a empty OpenGL scene works 100% without generating vertex arrays.

Here is my `go env`

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/<user>/Projects/<project>"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/lib/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build983667275=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
```

The function making the call:

```
var vertexArrayID uint32

// ERROR ON LINE BELOW.
gl.GenVertexArrays(1, &vertexArrayID)

gl.BindVertexArray(vertexArrayID)

// Vertex buffer
var vertexBuffer uint32
gl.GenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer)
gl.BindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer)
gl.BufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, len(verticies)*4, gl.Ptr(verticies), gl.STATIC_DRAW)
```

Thank you

Comment: Without seeing your code this is a guess: you're trying to ask for a VertexArray whose identifier will be stored in an empty var.

Comment: @Ripi2 I've updated my question with the code causing the error. Hope it gives more context regarding the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the a OpenGL context was created after the function call instead of before. Very strange that the empty scene still worked and only crashed after trying to generate buffers.